# Using several transforms in one Entity

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, transform, qt3d

Tried to create simple program showing torus with lighting. Everything works, but have this problem with light position.

When trying to create new transform for light after creating torus light's transform is being used for new torus position, instead of light.

Tried to change values and move addComponent, but no result.

[Here's photo of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ce1fk.png)

Here's my entire code.

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <Qt3DExtras/Qt3DWindow>
#include <Qt3DExtras/QTorusMesh>
#include <Qt3DExtras/QPhongMaterial>
#include <Qt3DCore/QEntity>
#include <Qt3DCore/QTransform>
#include <Qt3DRender/QCamera>
#include <Qt3DRender/QPointLight>

Qt3DCore::QEntity *createScene();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow view;

    Qt3DCore::QEntity *rootEntity = createScene();

    Qt3DRender::QCamera *camera =view.camera();
    camera->lens()->setPerspectiveProjection(60,(float)view.width()/view.height(),0.1f,1000.0f);
    camera->setPosition(QVector3D(0.0f,0.0f,40.0f));
    camera->setViewCenter(QVector3D(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f));

    view.setRootEntity(rootEntity);
    view.show();
    return app.exec();
}

Qt3DCore::QEntity *createScene()
{
    Qt3DCore::QEntity *resultEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity;

    Qt3DExtras::QTorusMesh *torusMesh = new Qt3DExtras::QTorusMesh(resultEntity);
    torusMesh->setRadius(15.0f);
    torusMesh->setMinorRadius(6.0f);
    torusMesh->setSlices(16);
    torusMesh->setRings(32);

    Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial *torusMaterial = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial(resultEntity);

    Qt3DCore::QTransform *torusTransform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform(resultEntity);

    resultEntity->addComponent(torusMesh);
    resultEntity->addComponent(torusMaterial);
    resultEntity->addComponent(torusTransform);

    Qt3DCore::QEntity *lightEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(resultEntity);

    Qt3DRender::QPointLight *pointLight = new Qt3DRender::QPointLight(lightEntity);

    Qt3DCore::QTransform *lightTransform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform(resultEntity);
    lightTransform->setTranslation(QVector3D(0.0f,0.0f,30.0f));

    resultEntity->addComponent(pointLight);
    resultEntity->addComponent(lightTransform);

    return resultEntity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
resultEntity->addComponent(pointLight);
```

Which assigns `pointLight` as component of `resultEntity`, but `pointLight` must be a component of `LightEntity`, `LightEntity` has yet `resultEntity` as parent.

```
resultEntity->addComponent(lightTransform);
```

And this, which assigns `lightTransform` as component of `resultEntity`, and it's wrong because you want `lightTransform` to affect only to `lightEntity`.

Use these:

```
lightEntity->addComponent(pointLight);
lightEntity->addComponent(lightTransform);
```